# import python module in home directory in CGI script

Tags: python, cgi, python-import

I have a CGI script that needs mechanize, but it is not installed system wide on my web host. I installed it in my home directory

```
$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg
```

However my CGI script cannot import mechanize

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys,cgi,cgitb
import mechanize
^-- Exception(import mechanize ImportError: cannot import name mechanize)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: are you sure the cgi script isn't running as a different user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your cgi script is running as a different user (possibly apache or root), so Python won't use the the site-packages directory in your home folder.

What you probably want to do here is add the site-packages directory in your home folder to the list of site directories that will be used by the entire system.

You can do this by adding the file `sitecustomize.py` with the following contents in your Python installation's site-packages directory:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/home/YOUR_USER/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

In case it isn't obvious, replace `/home/YOUR_USER` with the actual path to your home directory.

You can find where the Python installation site-packages directory is using the following command:

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"
```